# ng-grid - editing then updating remote. How?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am using `ng-grid` and I am trying to automatically update a single model when data in the grid-table changes. For that I am using the edit module of `ng-grid`.

This is the code of my controller:

```
# Define app
app = angular.module("app", ["ng-rails-csrf", "rails", 'ngTagsInput', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit'])


app = angular.module("app")

app.controller "UsersController", ["$scope", "User", ($scope, User)->
  $scope.init = ->
    User.query({}).then((results)->
      console.log results
      $scope.gridOptions.data = results
  )

  $scope.gridOptions =
    enableFiltering: true
    columnDefs: [
      {field: 'id'}
      {field: 'email', enableCellEdit: true, type: 'string'}
      {field: 'firstName', enableCellEdit: true, type: 'string'}
      {field: 'lastName', enableCellEdit: true, type: 'string'}
      {field: 'lastName', enableCellEdit: true, type: 'string'}
    ]

  $scope.init()

  $scope.$watch 'gridOptions.data', (newValue, oldValue)->
    console.log "new value"
    console.log newValue
    console.log "old value"
    console.log oldValue
    # FIXME this causes a lot of updates to the remote
  , true
]

html:
.users-list
  .my-grid ui-grid="gridOptions" ui-grid-edit="ui-grid-edit"
```

Is there a better way to do it? Like calling an update function whenever one of the model changes?

Comment: look at `$watchCollection()` vs the `$watch(func..,true` for deep-linking

Comment: What would that change in my code? It would be called less often? Thanks!

Comment: Here's a good article on them -http://teropa.info/blog/2014/01/26/the-three-watch-depths-of-angularjs.html.

Comment: To lessen the amount of calls also look at debounce -https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions

Comment: Ok thanks. Good reads for sure. But how do I add that to the ng-grid in the view? I have not found a way yet to modify the individual table cells.

Comment: Yeah I looked at that, I don't know enough about `ng-grid` sorry,  I know it's moving to `ui-grid`. I think you want to use lodash and it's debounce with $apply inside your watch.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you can use angular debounce or how it applies to the model on your grid.

Maybe something like?

```
<input ng-model="gridOptions.data" ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default': 700} }"/>
```

With lodash / underscore it looks like.

```
$scope.$watch('gridOptions.data', _.debounce(function (value) {
    $scope.$apply(function(){
        ...
    })
}, 700));
```